# AI learning through natural selection

Tags: lua, emulation

I am attempting to do this through Lua on the BizHawk emulator. https://pastebin.com/ydkTAdMP
Whenever I run this code the first generation works just fine, but with the 2nd generation it never increases the NSI table. It leaves the next part of the table blank, giving me this error message:

```
NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:38: attempt to compare number with nil
```

Side Note: The reason why the NSI table is so limited is because it's easier for me to work with smaller numbers first.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. You should edit your post to include the relevant code instead of just having a link to it on another site.

Comment: I don't know where it messed up, and apparently there has to be more actual text than code.